# Opencart 3.0.3.8: Internal Server Error Popup at Checkout. Error Log is empty

Tags: localhost, opencart, mamp, internal-server-error, opencart-3

first off all - Error Log is empty. So my problem is that at 1st Step in Checkout page when I click "**CONTINUE**" I get Internal Server Error Popup:

[image: Internal Server Error popup at Checkout 1st step. (Opencart)]

and Inspect Tools -> console shows this information:

[image]

"[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

http://localhost/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/country&country_id=123

[image]

Same thing with admin panel but this Popup only happens when clicking "Dashboard" on left sidebar for like 5 times in a row after each time it loads dashboard page. Discovered this error randomly...  After getting this error in this way then it happens everytime I try to click "Dashboard" and it loads. Same Internal Server Error popup but console shows different Error:

"[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

http://localhost/admin/index.php?route=extension/dashboard/map/map&user_token=fHdKojJ8E1oUT8yLpFgksxSAEaPwEhrP

[image]

[image]

**My server and tools, etc:**

- Localhost MAMP 6.6
- PHP 7.4.21, also tried 7.3, older versions not supported by Opencart or Theme.
- MySQL 5.7.34
- Opencart 3.0.3.8. Tried
  3.0.3.7 and 3.0.3.6 as well.
- Browser: Safari

***P.S - when I restart Apache server on Mamp the Errors are gone until I click Dashboard on admin panel for too many times.***
***P.S.S - no extensions installed. Completely fresh Opencart installation, only Journaled Theme installed.***

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check the log file

Comment: @YazanFouadAldbaisy no errors, even when enabling advanced error logging in php.ini, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Directory and open index.php file
add the below code in the file and save it will shows you the error instead of Internal Server Error Popup

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```